# regular expression not work when sending paramter

Tags: python, django

i use django 1.1 and python 3.6, i make view show detail for one product but when i send id for product to view it not work but  when i change in urlpatterns the regular expression to be different with products list view it work.

example:(not working code)

```
 urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^products/', productslistview.as_view()),
    url(r'^products-f/', product_list_view),
    url(r'^products/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', productdetailview.as_view()),
    url(r'^products-f/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', product_detail_view),
]
```

and when i changed to(working code)

```
url(r'^products-d/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', productdetailview.as_view()),
url(r'^products-f-d/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', product_detail_view),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't terminate your product_list_view pattern, so it matches everything beginning with "products-f". You need a $:

```
url(r'^products-f/$', product_list_view),
```